Response.data/Response.error Issue. Not defined for type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
I's working on an app that retrieves data from a flutter database but I'm having issues with my fetch queries.
Fetch method:
void _fetchUserData() async {
    // Assuming you store the current user session and it has a valid token
    final user = Supabase.instance.client.auth.currentUser;
    if (user != null) {
      setState(() {
        _userId = user.id; // Set the user ID
      });

      // Fetch the user profile data
      final response = await Supabase.instance.client
          .from('user_profiles')
          .select()
          .eq('id', user.id)
          .single();

      if (response.data != null) {
        // Update the state with fetched data
        setState(() {
          // Assuming 'date_of_birth', 'gender', and 'id_number' are columns in your 'profiles' table
          _dobController.text = response.data['date_of_birth'];
          _genderController.text = response.data['gender'];
          _idController.text = response.data['id_number'];
        });
      } else if (response.error != null) {
        // Handle the error
        _showSnackBar(response.error.message);
      }
    }
  }

Error messages:
The getter 'data' isn't defined for the type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.
Try importing the library that defines 'data', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'data'.
The getter 'error' isn't defined for the type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.
Try importing the library that defines 'error', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'error'.
I'm not sure why I'm getting this error message as I've seen many examples using response.data and response.error. Is there a fix for this or an alternative method of getting the response?

ensure that response's data and error get initialized, it's a deserialization problem

I'm not quite sure where to do that, how would I go about initializing them?

First, you need to parse your response into JSON format, then you can use your response. Please find the below code; I think this code will help you.
  Map<String,dynamic> responseData=json.decode(response) as Map<String, dynamic>; 


if (responseData['data'] != null) {   
   
setState(() {
_dobController.text = responseData['data']['date_of_birth'];
 _genderController.text =responseData['data']['gender'];
  _idController.text = responseData['data']['id_number']; }); 

} else if (responseData['error'] != null) {
_showSnackBar(responseData['error']['message']);
}

 


 
     
      
     
     
    
  
     
    
  

